# how to fix this code for nxt bluetooth?

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am a student working for something big. Can you help me to finish the code?

It shows 2 errors for name that can't be found in the code and 4 that doesn't exist in the current context.

It is a code for pc communicating to lego mindstorm nxt brick.

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void send1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string messagesend;
        messagesend = textBox2.Text;

        string Command;
        int ReplyLength;
        string _serialPort;
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();

        SerialPort BluetoothConnection = new SerialPort();
        BluetoothConnection.PortName = "COM3";
        // Replace this COM port by the appropriate one on your computer
        BluetoothConnection.Open();
        BluetoothConnection.ReadTimeout = 1500;
        BluetoothConnection.Write(Command, 0, Command.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < ReplyLength; i++)
        {
            textBox2.Text += BluetoothConnection.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
        }
        BluetoothConnection.Close(); 
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

is this correct?

Comment: Welcome ob Stack Overflow! Unfortunately we can not "finish" your code. But if you explain a little more detailed at what errors you got stuck, someone may know and tell you hire to fix them. (What names can't be found, what 4 don't exist? )

Comment: I added some missing objects: Command, ReplyLength, and SerialPort